# How do I create an Actor that has non-serialisable dependencies on a remote node?

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

Suppose you have an Actor, `MyActor`, which depends on an object which cannot be serialised. Examples include:

- a Jackson `ObjectMapper`, for manipulating Json
- a service of some kind obtained from a DI container

The `Props` for such an actor might look like this in Java:

```
public static Props props(ObjectMapper m, SomeService s) {
    return Props.create(new Creator<MyActor>() {
        @Override
        public MyActor create() throws Exception {
            return new MyActor(m, s);
        }
    });
}
```

The dependencies are passed into the constructor of the Actor. The problem is that this will not work in a clustered environment: these objects are not serialisable so trying to create the actor on a remote node will fail.

How do we solve this problem **without** using static global state?

Answer (score 0):

There can be different types of the solution, it depends on your needs.

You can wrap the service for example in the Cluster Singleton and then send the actor ref to it across the cluster, your actor props then will have signature like this:
`public static Props props(ActorRef refToMapperWrapper, ActorRef refToServiceWrapper)`.

The other solution is to instantiate new service and object mapper on the node you need it. You then should send the objects needed to create Service/ObjectMapper (i.e. constructor args) between the nodes, so these objects should be serialised somehow.

The ObjectMapper should better be created on each of the nodes independently, its configuration however can be sent across the nodes.

Comment: I don't think the actor ref solution works. To take the ObjectMapper example, it doesn't make any sense to have to communicate with another actor every time you need to read some json.

Regarding your second solution, I agree that the object mapper needs to be instantiated on each node independently. The question is how to get a reference to it inside the actor. Yes, I could have the actor create it based on configuration, but there is a reason that we tend not to do that (dependency injection principles)